# What is using all this memory for a google ndb fetch?

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

When I fetch 1000 of my models from the datastore, it uses a lot more memory than expected. My datastore indicates that I have >18000 but the total size is 8.31MB

```
Application 18025 8.31 MB
```

Here is the code for fetching the entities, with the caches disabled

```
def memoryForAThousandApplicationsNoCache():
  ndb_ctx = ndb.get_context()
  ndb_ctx.set_cache_policy(lambda key: False)
  ndb_ctx.set_memcache_policy(lambda key: False)
  startUsage = memory_usage().current()
  applications = Application.query().fetch(1000)
  return "Memory usage after applications:  %d MB" % (memory_usage().current() - startUsage)
```

and I get

```
Memory usage after applications: 10 MB
```

What is consuming all this memory? Am I misusing memory_usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you haven't had any reason to profile or dig in to Python memory usage outside of App Engine. Along with the many benefits that come from objects, there's a surprising (to low-level programmers) amount of overhead when representing things as Python objects. And when you're using something like `ndb`, there are extra (Python) data structures behind the scenes.

Google for "python memory overhead" to find more background. There's a decent graph [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22999766/data-size-in-memory-vs-on-disk/30008338#30008338) that may be instructive.